# What is the difference between queue and queue discipline in ns3?

Tags: c++, ns-3

I found that there are two classes about the queue in NS3

The first one is the https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/src/network/utils/queue.h, which is named queue and a drop tail queue is implemented based on this.

The other is the https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/src/traffic-control/model/queue-disc.h, which is named queue discipline and many queue are implemented

I now want to know what's the difference between these two notations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to encourage you to read the [*ns-3* tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/singlehtml/). You will find many of the answers to your questions there.

Queue and QueueDisc are not merely notations, they're distinct objects that serve distinct purposes. According to the [*ns-3* tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/singlehtml/#queues-in-ns-3),

> Architecturally, ns-3 separates the device layer from the IP layers or traffic control layers of an Internet host. Since recent releases of ns-3, outgoing packets traverse two queueing layers before reaching the channel object. The first queueing layer encountered is what is called the ‘traffic control layer’ in ns-3; here, active queue management (RFC7567) and prioritization due to quality-of-service (QoS) takes place in a device-independent manner through the use of queueing disciplines. The second queueing layer is typically found in the NetDevice objects. Different devices (e.g. LTE, Wi-Fi) have different implementations of these queues.

So, Queue's are the lowest level objects that actually store packets. A QueueDisc is an abstract class that provides a queue-like interface, but it actually implements [Active Queue Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_queue_management) (AQM). More information about QueueDiscs can be found in the 'Detailed Description' section of the [QueueDisc API documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_queue_disc.html).

An implementation detail specific to *ns-3*: QueueDisc's actually encapsulate a Queue. This makes sense since a QueueDisc still needs to store the packets it gets.

You will find many of *ns-3*'s interfaces attempt to mirror the network subsystem of Linux.